# kml to layer error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, convert, kml

I tried to use the "KML to Layer" tool in ArcMap 10.2.2 but it always end up in an error showed up the the following image. I hide the directory of the kml file in the image since it does contain my name in it. Please bear with me.

I have been wasting my time for the past 2 hours trying to figure this out.

[image: kml error]

Comment: *does* it have anything in it? I have found that QGIS is a bit more robust at importing KML files, load the data and save as shapefile. Global Mapper also does this better than Esri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this useful to you please try once

http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vp0000000t000401.htm

Comment: Ah, I finally got it. Yes, it works once I changed the "output extent" in Environment settings to "same as layer"basemap" rather than default. Don't really know why I need to change it since it works for other kmls I had before, but thanks anyways! Hope whoever had the same problem can find this post!